# Installing Tkinter offline

Tags: software-installation, python, offline, tkinter

I don't have an internet connection in my Ubuntu. I would like to install tkinter. So is there any way to install tkinter and its dependencies offline ?

Note: I don't have any Ubuntu system that is connected to the internet.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I don't have a system connected to internet.

Comment: Then how are you posting here ?

Comment: I'm using internet on my windows system.

Comment: So use one of the answers in the question I gave you that uses windows , there are several to choose from. Cube is one of the options - https://launchpad.net/cube-server "Download applications on any internet connected computers (Linux or Windows), and install it back to your computer, offline"

Comment: @bodhi.zazen In order to download cube over windows we need to first install cube on ubuntu. When i'm trying to install cube it's giving me `error while loading shared libraries: libfuse.so.2`.Can you please help me ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65297/discussion-between-codeit-and-bodhi-zazen).

Comment: Please read the links I give you. From the launchpad page I gave you -
 https://launchpad.net/cube-server/trunk/0.1/+download/cube-server-tutorial.pdf . That pdf gives detailed instructions "Beforewebeginwiththesetup,pleaseseetoitthatyouhavethesefiles:1)cube-server-installer*.zip-Thiscontainsthecube-serverinstallerforLinux.2)cube-server-portable*.zip-Thiscontainsaportablecube-serverforWindows.YoucandownloadbothinstallersfromLaunchpadDownloadPagehttps://launchpad.net/cube-server/+downloadYoucanplacetheminyourcomputerorflashdriveforlateruse."

Comment: The .zip files have everything you need and can be downloaded and extracted on your windows box and then used to install what you need on Ubuntu.